# Re Get latest address of a person in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a query to see person details but I see multiple address for a single person.

```
SELECT  Name
      , RTRIM(Address1) + ' | ' + RTRIM(Address2) + ' | ' + RTRIM(Address3) 
        + ' | ' + RTRIM(Address4)) + ' | ' + RTRIM(Address5)) 
        + ' | ' + RTRIM(PostCode) AS Address
      , Phone 
from Persons
```

Result set:

```
╔══════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Name ║                            Address                            ║ Phone ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ ABC  ║ 44A Sun Street |  |  | Waltham Abbey | Essex | EN9 1EJ        ║   123 ║
║ ABC  ║ Abbey Lodge Pick Hill |  |  | Waltham Abbey | Essex | EN9 3LE ║   123 ║
╚══════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Tried this:

```
SELECT Name
     , RTRIM(MAX(Address1)) + ' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address2)) +' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address3) 
       + ' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address4)) + ' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address5)) + ' | ' 
       + RTRIM(MAX(PostCode))
    , Phone 
from Persons
```

but it still shows up 2 records.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You have no `where` clause.  Of course they both return the same number of records.

Comment: Why not get the max id from the table and get those values from there? `SELECT * FROM persons inner join (select max(id) from persons group by name) maxperson on persons.id = maxperson.id` though I do believe there is a much beautiful way of getting these data.

Comment: Show sample and expected data please.

Comment: if `Persons` is a plain table, you have two records with same name and different addresses. if `Persons` is a view, there is a wrong join in the view

Comment: @EduardDaduya There is... Use row_number

Comment: @NEER I think his Address1 - Address5 is equivalent to Lot, Blk No, St, etc.. based on OP edit.

Comment: Have you noticed as soon as your question was properly formatted and people could actually make some sense of it you have been given two answers. A well formatted , easy to read and understand question is more likely to get a response.

Comment: @MtwStark: Persons is a view and I am trying to change joins and check data

Comment: @All - Thanks for prompt responses

Comment: glad to be of help, if you found it useful, please accept the answer that best fits

Answer (score 1):

you are running a simple `SELECT SomeFields FROM Persons`,

there is no way to duplicate records in this statement,
so the duplicates must already be in `Persons`.

If `Persons` is a table, you have two records with same name and different addresses.

If `Persons` is a view, you have to check for the view definition, most probably there is a wrong join inside the view causing the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use a row_number()

```
select *
from (

    select [ADDRESS_GUMF],  -- your big concat 
    row_number() over( partition by A1.NAME order by A1.ADDRESS desc) as ADD_ORD -- Would be better if you had a date or id field in here, replace the order by if you do
    from ADDRESS A1
)
where ADD_ORD = 1
```

Comment: This right here is what I was talking about, but I'd rather go for `A1.ID` desc rather than `A1.ADDRESS desc` simply because arranging the address in desc order will not yield the LATEST entry.

Comment: @EduardDaduya I would too, but he doesn't say whether he has one or not

Comment: And thus, the mystery continue.. Stay Tuned!

Comment: the question was about duplicate rows not expected, not about how to choice one of them.

Comment: @MtwStark And I was being helpful, offering a solution in addition to a diagnosis of the problem. Just wanted to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will get you last address based on the order in which data placed in the table.

```
WITH cte_1
AS
  (  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY A1.NAME order by (select 1)) as RNO,
          Name, RTRIM(MAX(Address1)) + ' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address2)) +' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address3) 
       + ' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address4)) + ' | ' + RTRIM(MAX(Address5)) + ' | ' 
       + RTRIM(MAX(PostCode)) [Address],Phone 
    from ADDRESS A1
)
SELECT Name,[Address],Phone
FROM cte_1
WHERE RNO= 1
```

Comment: the question was about duplicate rows not expected, not about how to choice one of them. Also, your answer does not guarantee the insertion order

Comment: @mtwStark we can't simply predict and give a solution by seeing a question with out enough clarification. if the database is not normalized there may be a chance of storing data like this and i suggest a way to eliminate records by keeping one entry .Since there is not information of id in the date column , i have ordered  it with a value for getting the right order. sometime before only the user confirmed that it a view and you gave comments to all other the answers with a negative vote.

Comment: in my humble opinion, if the question was not clear, you should ask for clarification, and not to add an unuseful answer which only makes confusion. the main problem here is to understand questions.. if I ask you because my apple is blue, you should not answer me to paint it red or green.. in addition, `select 1` in `row_number()` does not gives out the order of the insertion of records in table as you stated, but most probably will give the clustered index order or any other order the optimizer will use to extract the records.

Comment: its not a matter of apple or orange.you have also given logical guess like what we did. again about the order in row_number(),just try with a sample and then comment.

Comment: about the order in row_number(), I know what I'm talking about, you should try it by yourself before to talk.. 
`CREATE TABLE [test_order](
 [id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 [desc] [varchar](10) NULL
) 
GO
insert into test_order values (3,'desc id 3');
insert into test_order values (2,'desc id 2');
insert into test_order values (1,'desc id 1');
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) test_order, * from test_order;`